# How import on Typescript?

Tags: typescript, import, importerror

I am trying to import a class, when doing so I get the following error:

```ts
import { Work } from 'work';
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'work'

But if I change it to:

```ts
import { Work } from './work';
```

No error, module imported. Is there a way to get it to work without having to add anything to the import?

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2022",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "baseUrl": "./",                                     /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*"]
    },                                                   /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                                  /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,                /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                                /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

File structure: [project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQeav.png)

Comment: Can you send your file structure?

Comment: @EpicPuppy613 If I already added it, thanks.

Comment: Importing a bare module name generally means you're importing a package you fetched with `npm` and Node is going to look in your project's `node_modules` directory and the global equivalent. There's a search path for this which you could modify to include the current directory, but that's considered bad form. When people read `import { Work } from 'work'` they're going to assume `work` is an NPM module and you should follow this convention unless you have a good reason not to. "I don't want to have to type `./` all the time" isn't a good enough reason.

Comment: @kindall I understand, thank you very much for the explanation, I'll use the alias '@' to keep everything organized and follow the convention correctly.